# JTable don't add First cell its empty

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

Jtable shows an empty cell for first cell here is code:

```
     DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
     table = new JTable(model){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
               return false; //Disallow the editing of any cell
             }};

          model.addColumn("JobID");                                              
                  model.addColumn("Job Location");
                  model.addColumn("Job Size");
                  model.addRow(new Object[]{"r5","2","3"});
```

output is

```
ID         Location     Size
(*)        2            3
```

`*` empty for cell (1,1)

Please help.

Comment: If I use the same code it works perfectly fine is there anyother piece of code which is involved here ?

Answer (score 2):

this code is correct for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), there must be another Whatever that generated ...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class DefTabMod extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DefTabMod() {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                return false; //Disallow the editing of any cell
            }
        };

        model.addColumn("JobID");
        model.addColumn("Job Location");
        model.addColumn("Job Size");
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"r5", "2", "3"});
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DefTabMod frame = new DefTabMod();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the key thing here is this line:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

it solves all things!